# How to write PHP code that repeats itself per array value

Tags: php, compression, code-generation, google-closure-compiler

I'm using Closure Compiler to compress and join a few JavaScript files the syntax is something like this;

```
$c = new PhpClosure();
$c->add("JavaScriptA.js")
  ->add("JavaScriptB.js")
  ->write();
```

How could I make it systematically add more files from an array? Let's say for each array element in `$file = array('JavaScriptA.js','JavaScriptB.js','JavaScriptC.js',..)` it would execute the following code

```
$c = new PhpClosure();    
$c->add("JavaScriptA.js")
  ->add("JavaScriptB.js")
  ->add("JavaScriptC.js")
  ->add
  ...
  ->write();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PhpClosure code uses [method chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining) to reduce repeated code and make everything look slightly nicer. The functions (or at least the `add` function) returns `$this` (The object the function was called on).

The code in the first sample could be written as:

```
$c = new PhpClosure();
$c->add("JavaScriptA.js");
$c->add("JavaScriptB.js");
$c->write();
```

The middle section (The `add` function calls) can then be transformed so that it loops over an array of files rather than having to add a line for each file.

```
$files = array("JavaScriptA.js", "JavaScriptB.js");
$c = new PhpClosure();
foreach ( $files as $file ){
    $c->add($file);
}
$c->write();
```

Comment: Or, to be exactly like his code, you would say `$c = $c->add($file);`. It may not make a difference, but that depends on the class implementation.

Comment: @bradlis7 `add()` returns `$this`. http://code.google.com/p/php-closure/source/browse/trunk/php-closure.php

Comment: Well then there's no need for it. I have not messed with closure before.

Comment: @bradlis7 It was a very valid point though and I must admit I didn't check the source until you mentioned it :)